# How to select a toolchain that matches SDK in Xcode14.3

Tags: ios, xcode14.3

I got a error while adding a package "this SDK is not supported by the compiler (the SDK is built with 'Apple Swift version 5.5.2 (swiftlang-1300.0.47.5 clang-1300.0.29.30)', while this compiler is 'Apple Swift version 5.8 (swiftlang-5.8.0.124.2 clang-1403.0.22.11.100)'). Please select a toolchain which matches the SDK."

How to resolve this issue?

I am not able to find toolchain option in Xcode 14.3 to install older swift version. Can anyone please help on this